# C++ Program Ending after cin assuming value is 0

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that calculates card balances for a game called Magic the Gathering, but whenever I try to run this program it stops at the first "cin" in main and the debugging says its making numMana 0. I'm new to c++ and I know I could've divided it up into more functions or classes or whatever they're called in c++. Any help you could give me would be much appreciated.

Thanks for any and all of your help,
Grant

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

float getGreen(void);
float getBlue(void);
float getRed(void);
float getBlack(void);
float getWhite(void);
int cardNum(void);
int numMana;
float color;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "How many mana are there total on the cards" << endl;
    cout << "not counting multi-colored" << endl;
    cin >> numMana;
    cout << endl;

    float green(getGreen());
    float blue(getBlue());
    float red(getRed());
    float black(getBlack());
    float white(getWhite());
    int cardsPre(cardNum());

    int numGreen, numBlue, numRed, numBlack, numWhite, mana, totalCards, totalMana;

    string name;

    mana = (cardsPre / 2);

    numGreen = green * mana;
    numBlue = blue * mana;
    numBlack = black * mana;
    numRed = red * mana;
    numWhite = white * mana;

    totalMana = numWhite + numRed + numGreen + numBlue + numBlack;
    totalCards = mana + totalMana;

    cout << "What would you like to name your deck?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl;

    cout << name << " has the following percents of each color" << endl;
    cout << green << "% of green" << endl;
    cout << blue << "% of blue" << endl;
    cout << red << "% of red" << endl;
    cout << black << "% of black" << endl;
    cout << white << "% of white" << endl;
    cout << "You need" <<numGreen << " green mana" <<endl;
    cout << "You need" <<numBlue << " blue mana" << endl;
    cout << "You need" <<numRed << " red mana" << endl;
    cout << "You need" <<numBlack << " black mana" << endl;
    cout << "You need" <<numWhite << " white mana" << endl;
    cout << "You will have" <<totalCards <<" cards in your deck";
    return 0;
}

float getGreen(void)
{
    cout << "How much green mana is there total on your cards?" << endl;
    cin >> color;

    return color / numMana;
}
float getBlue(void)
{
    cout << "How much Blue mana is there total on your cards?" << endl;
    cin >> color;

    return color / numMana;
}
float getRed(void)
{
    cout << "How much Red mana is there total on your cards?" << endl;
    cin >> color;

    return color / numMana;
}
float getBlack(void)
{
    cout << "How much Black mana is there total on your cards?" << endl;
    cin >> color;

    return color / numMana;
}
float getWhite(void)
{
    cout << "How much White mana is there total on your cards?" << endl;
    cin >> color;

    return color / numMana;
}
int cardNum(void)
{
    int ans;

    cout << "How many cards do you have (Not counting mana)" << endl;
    cin >> ans;

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: It works on my machine. You typed something that couldn't be converted to integer...

Comment: I'm not getting any problem.

Comment: The program seems to work fine except for %-calculation.
The output of each %-value should be multiplied with 100.

Comment: On mine I don't get a chance to make to enter anything this happens:http://imgur.com/hdRvAtK and I can't enter anything and pressing enter doesn't do anything

Comment: You seem to be running the program through the debugger 
and have set a breakpoint at `cin >> numMana;`
A breakpoint will "pause" the execution of a program at the specified line of source code.
Remove the breakpoint or try to run the program without the debugger attached.

Comment: Awesome that worked thanks so much this was my first real project in Xcode so I had no idea what the breakpoints were for. Again thanks so much